# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.google.devtools.build.lib.unix.ProcessUtils.getpid

Tags: java, bazel, bazel-rules, bazel-java

I am facing below issue with Bazel Info command ->

```
$bazel info                                                                                                                                                   
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
INFO: Invocation ID: 47f56fa4-a837-4636-97ef-57591ed4dcae
bazel-bin: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_rbansod/1cd1a8b9e1567ccf289777f2b0d30088/execroot/nsx/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin
bazel-genfiles: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_rbansod/1cd1a8b9e1567ccf289777f2b0d30088/execroot/nsx/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin
bazel-testlogs: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_rbansod/1cd1a8b9e1567ccf289777f2b0d30088/execroot/nsx/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/testlogs
character-encoding: file.encoding = ISO-8859-1, defaultCharset = ISO-8859-1
command_log: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_rbansod/1cd1a8b9e1567ccf289777f2b0d30088/command.log
committed-heap-size: 2147MB
execution_root: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_rbansod/1cd1a8b9e1567ccf289777f2b0d30088/execroot/nsx
gc-count: 4
gc-time: 28ms
install_base: /var/tmp/_bazel_rbansod/install/1cd9602f1e0e120a357e06b085ac3a74
java-home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home
java-runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 11.0.19+9-LTS-224) by Oracle Corporation
java-vm: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.19+9-LTS-224, mixed mode) by Oracle Corporation
max-heap-size: 2147MB
output_base: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_rbansod/1cd1a8b9e1567ccf289777f2b0d30088
output_path: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_rbansod/1cd1a8b9e1567ccf289777f2b0d30088/execroot/nsx/bazel-out
package_path: %workspace%
release: release 4.2.2
repository_cache: /var/tmp/_bazel_rbansod/cache/repos/v1
server_log: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_rbansod/1cd1a8b9e1567ccf289777f2b0d30088/java.log.rbansodj4h4v.rbansod.log.java.20231012-000350.91479
server_pid: FATAL: bazel crashed due to an internal error. Printing stack trace:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.google.devtools.build.lib.unix.ProcessUtils.getpid()I
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.unix.ProcessUtils.getpid(Native Method)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.util.ProcessUtils.getpid(ProcessUtils.java:51)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.runtime.commands.info.ServerPidInfoItem.get(ServerPidInfoItem.java:31)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.runtime.commands.InfoCommand.exec(InfoCommand.java:243)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.runtime.BlazeCommandDispatcher.execExclusively(BlazeCommandDispatcher.java:579)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.runtime.BlazeCommandDispatcher.exec(BlazeCommandDispatcher.java:231)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.server.GrpcServerImpl.executeCommand(GrpcServerImpl.java:543)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.server.GrpcServerImpl.lambda$run$1(GrpcServerImpl.java:606)
    at io.grpc.Context$1.run(Context.java:579)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

How can we resolve this issue?

Dev Machine is ->
Apple M1 Pro, Mac OS 13.5.2

Comment: Here it is https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/073fba498cd436fdf99067ed8bdcb023c78c7200/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/util/ProcessUtils.java#L42C1-L51C7.           ```@return the process ID of this process.
   * @throws UnsatisfiedLinkError when JNI is not available.```